# Obtener valor de checkbox manual y asignarlo a campo del modelo mvc c#

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc, razor

Soy novato en c#, Tengo una aplicación MVC c#, en mi tabla sql y en el modelo tengo definido un campo de tipo string llamado TipoFalla, en mi vista parcial _Create intento que ese campo sea un checkbox, en el cual los usuarios puedan seleccionar si es un incidente de tipo Hardware, Software o ambos, agregué este código para crear los checkbox:

```C#
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoFalla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-2">Hardware
     @Html.CheckBox("Hardware", new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Hardware", @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Sofware
     @Html.CheckBox("Software", new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Software", @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

En mi `Model.TipoFalla` deseo asignarle un valor de acuerdo a lo seleccionado en los `checkbox`.

Entiendo que mediante AJAX puedo obtener el valor de los `checkbox`, pero no sé como asignarle el valor correspondiente al `Model.TipoFalla`.

Gracias por su atención

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ese campo no es un string.. o son dos campos separados.. un checkbox es booleano... es si no... con lo cual, o haces una transformacion, o usas dos campos, o usas otro tipo de dato...

Comment: A nivel de usuario debe elegir entre 3 opciones, Hardware, Software o ambos, por eso intento hacerlo con 2 checkbox, y a nivel base de datos, almacenar como H, S, A. Mediante ajax obtengo si se seleccionó el primer checkbox, significa que en mi campo debo guardar el string "H", si el segundo guardar "S" y si ambos, guardar "A", lo que no sé es como asignarle ese valor desde ajax al campo del modelo en el formulario.

Comment: Lo que pasa, es que tratas de asignar un string, a algo que no devuelve un string. entonces necesitarias en tu modelo un valor intermedio que rescate esos dos valores, y guardar un valor calculado en base a esos dos, y a la vuelta lo mismo, al leer tenes que recalcular cada valor en base al valor del modelo...